# Ensuring app SQL select statement retrieve different rows

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL InnoDB table containing "tickets".  Tickets are either 'open', 'locked', 'closed'.  I have multiple remote client apps that run select queries on this table for 'open' tickets.  I want to ensure that the different clients don't retrieve the same rows.

My process flow right now is:

Issue select for open...
Update table set status to locked...
Do stuff with the ticket
Update table set status to closed.

Obviously there's a huge gaping race condition hole there between the time a client selects and open ticket and then locks it.  How do I prevent other clients accessing the same row in a non-blocking manner?

Comment: Standard isolation levels give priority to SELECT statements over INSERT/UPDATE/etc: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3393161/MySQL-Transactions-Part-II---Transaction-Isolation-Levels.htm

Comment: you can try using [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html)